# Silverlight Modal winth in container

Tags: silverlight, custom-controls, modal-dialog

Basically I want a modal form to show only within a certain container. Best way I can explain is with the use of a tab control.

So let's say you have 2 tabs and on tab 1 you open a modal window. Now tab 2 must still be accessible while the modal is open. The modal should just cover the contents of tab 1. The idea is that now I can go onto tab 2, do what ever I need, and then go back to tab 1 and still have the modal open as I left it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make use of silverlight floatwindow,

[Floating windows silverlight 4](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/121488/FloatingWindow-Multi-windows-Interface-for-Silverl)

Or you can make use of canvas, write a property to make it visible and hide , based on your requirement you can enable and disable it whenever you need

Comment: I've been working on this in the evenings when I have time, and it just doesn't work for what I want to do. At first I got errors while creating a tab and it's floating window contents on the fly. I got passed it eventually, but it's still not quite what I want and there is still some errors. I tried contacting the creator and I have not received any feedback. I see he has also taken down his website. So much for that then.

Basically, all I want is to add a window to my silverlight tab and only have the overlay apply to the inside of that tab.

Comment: I'll try the canvas idea.